# Why does "gem install passenger" fail with "undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger

Using RVM v1.25.22, when I try to install the `passenger` gem, it fails. Installing other gems, such as `pry`, succeeds.

```
[nick@app02 ~] gem install passenger
HEAD http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
…
Installing gem passenger-4.0.41
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.41/.gitignore
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.41/.travis.yml
...
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.41/test/tut/tut_reporter.h
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.41/test/valgrind-osx.supp
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Attempting to download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/4.0.41/rubyext-ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux.tar.gz into /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.41/download_cache
Attempting to download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/4.0.41/webhelper-1.4.7-x86_64-linux.tar.gz into /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.41/download_cache
Attempting to download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/4.0.41/support-x86_64-linux.tar.gz into /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.41/download_cache
make "DESTDIR="
true
make "DESTDIR=" install
true
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
[nick@app02 ~]  
[nick@app02 ~] echo $?
1
[nick@app02 ~]
```

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, I asked and answered the exact same question 9 months ago:

[Installing gems with extensions always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736654/installing-gems-with-extensions-always-fails)